# merging error in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframes that looks like this:

top_ten_movies:

```
movieId  count   mean   
1        247     3.872470
2        107     3.401869
6        104     3.884615
10       122     3.450820
25       101     3.742574
32       196     3.923469
34       148     3.601351
36       104     3.937500
39       120     3.550000
47       201     4.034826
```

movies:

```
movieId  title                                  genres
1        Toy Story (1995)                       Adventure
2        Jumanji (1995)                         Children|Fantasy
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)                Comedy|Romance
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)               Comedy|Drama|Romance
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995)     Comedy
6        Heat (1995)                            Action|Crime|Thriller
7        Sabrina (1995)                         Comedy|Romance
8        Tom and Huck (1995)                    Adventure|Children
9        Sudden Death (1995)                    Action
```

I need to merge based on the movieId, so:

```
required_data=pd.merge(top_ten_movies, movies)
required_data=pd.merge(top_ten_movies, movies, on='movieId', how='outer')
```

Both the statements are throwing the error. Can someone help...?

Comment: Would be useful to know the error don't you think? Are you sure that `movieId` dtypes are the same for both dfs? ie. is one numeric and the other is string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume these are you errors for the methods you are trying respectively:

> MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on
>
> KeyError: 'movieId'

From the DataFrames you posted I assume that your index is `movieId`, that is what is leading to your errors. If you reset your indices and try again you should be able to merge. So based on these assumptions the following should work:

```
out = pd.merge(top_ten_movies.reset_index(), movies.reset_index())
print(out)
   movieId  count      mean                 genres      title
0        1    247  3.872470              Adventure  Toy Story
1        2    107  3.401869       Children|Fantasy    Jumanji
2        6    104  3.884615  Action|Crime|Thriller       Heat
```

Now if your index is `movieId` as assumed, you can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method to accomplish your task. For example:

```
print(top_ten_movies.join(movies))
         count      mean                 genres      title
movieId
1          247  3.872470              Adventure  Toy Story
2          107  3.401869       Children|Fantasy    Jumanji
6          104  3.884615  Action|Crime|Thriller       Heat
10         122  3.450820                    NaN        NaN
25         101  3.742574                    NaN        NaN
32         196  3.923469                    NaN        NaN
34         148  3.601351                    NaN        NaN
36         104  3.937500                    NaN        NaN
39         120  3.550000                    NaN        NaN
47         201  4.034826                    NaN        NaN
print(top_ten_movies.join(movies, how='inner'))
         count      mean                 genres      title
movieId
1          247  3.872470              Adventure  Toy Story
2          107  3.401869       Children|Fantasy    Jumanji
6          104  3.884615  Action|Crime|Thriller       Heat
```

All this being said the best thing you could do for yourself is to read [Merge, Join, and Concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in the pandas documentation.